# How to populate model data from json file

Tags: json, backbone.js, model

I currently have to code below and a static json file. However how can I set my model defaults to the data in the json file? My JSON file has a few pages - I want to be able to get defaults and set defaults.

```
var PageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
initialize: function () {
    console.log('initiliazed model');
},

url: "data/data.json",

defaults: function() {
    return PageView.defaultsFromJSON;
}

});

var PageView = Backbone.View.extend ({
initialize: function () {
    console.log('initiliazed view')
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.model.fetch();
    this.render();
    this.model.on('change',this.render);
},

el : '#ev-wrapper',

render: function () {
    $('#ev-wrapper').append(Handlebars.compile($('#ev-template').html())(this.model.toJSON()));

    $('.ev-asset-loader').fadeOut('slow', function (event) {
        this.remove();

    });
}

});

pageModel = new PageView({model: new PageModel()});
```

json file -

```
{
"page":[{
        "id":"p05",
        "title":"ptitle1",
        "text":"pinitialtext"
},
{
        "id":"p10",
        "title":"ptitle2",
        "text":"pinitialtext"
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you rendering the page with a server-side language ? If yes, inject a JSON string into the view containing your defaults, and fill your model with it.

```
var data = <?php echo $json ?>, 
    model = new PageModel(data),
    view = new PageView({model: model, el : $('#ev-wrapper')[0]});
```

If you are not using a server-side language, I think you could issue an AJAX request with JQuery to load your JSON data, but this would be the same as calling `fetch`.

I can't see a way to "include" the JSON file another way.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to solve a similar problem (Populating Backbone models from a static JSON file for a demo).

I came across an example on the Backbone.Leaflet library: 
https://github.com/LuizArmesto/backbone.leaflet/blob/master/examples/map.html

```
 // This isn't the backbone way, but we want to keep this example
  // as simple as possible.
  $( '#render' ).click( function () {
    geoCollection.reset( JSON.parse( $( '#geoJSON' ).val() ) );
  });
```

In this example, the ID in question (#geoJSON) is a text area that houses the JSON the author (LuizArmesto) is trying to load into the model.

```
 <textarea id="geoJSON">
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[[-46.6155, -23.5023], [-46.6193, -23.5030], [-46.6247, -23.5073], [-46.6252, -23.5117], [-46.6218, -23.5115], [-46.6154, -23.5080], [-46.6150, -23.5037], [-46.6155, -23.5023]]]
      },
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [[-46.6318, -23.4900], [-46.6256, -23.4916], [-46.6200, -23.4900], [-46.6100, -23.4900]]
      },
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-46.6368, -23.5100]
      },
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-46.6156, -23.5016]
      },
      "properties": {}
    }
  ]
}

</textarea>
```

As stated in his comments, this isn't idiomatic of backbone (or "the backbone way"), but it works great for little side projects that don't need a server.